# Permission denied while udating excel sheet

Tags: python, pandas

With code

```py
pd.ExcelWriter("K:\\PYTHON MATERIALS\\TestData.xlsx",engine="openpyxl",mode="a") as writer:
    comments_df.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='Comments'+str(today_date.year),index=False)
```

I am getting this error while writing data to excel sheet

`self.fp = io.open(file, filemode) PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'K:\\PYTHON MATERIALS\\TestData.xlsx'`

Comment: This is usually because you have the document already open in excel

Comment: this document is not opened anywhere.

Comment: How are you running this code? e.g. from a command prompt window